# How to mock a protected method of 3rd party code

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Using Mockito I want to mock a property of a class so I can verify the output

```
public class MyClass extends ThirdPartyFramework {
  Output goesHere;

  @Override
  protected setup(){
    goesHere = new Output();
  }

  //...      
}

public abstract class ThirdPartyFramework {
  protected setup(){...}
  //...
}
```

I need to inject a mock of the Output class so I can validate that my code wrote the correct output.

- But I can't just `@InjectMock` because the `setup()` method is called
  mid-runtime and overwrites my injection.
- And I can't just make setup public in `MyClass` because the test code I'm working
  with is generic and needs to work for all subclasses of
  `ThirdPartyFramework`, so I only have a reference to `ThirdPartyFramework`, meaning `setup()` is protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by wrapping `ThirdPartyFramework` and placing that class in the same package as the `ThirdPartyFramework` class.

That way I could mock the protected methods with Mockito. Then I was able to use `@InjectMock` to inject a mock of the `Output` object and control its method calls via that mock.

Comment: +1 I was just about to supply an answer along these lines myself.  Always wrap your third party libraries with something that you CAN actually mock in the way that you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Are you set on Mockito? I am asking since [Mockito FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ)Mockito FAQ states that it doesn't support mocking static methods, which I guess you'd need in this case for the setup method to create your mock instead of real Output.

I have used PowerMock for a similar scenario:

```
whenNew(NewInstanceClass.class).withArguments(any()).thenReturn(mockObject);
```

which says that each time a NewInstanceClass gets created my mockObject be returned no matter what constructor arguments had been used and who constructed NewInstanceClass at what time.

In PowerMock docs I've also found following example:

```
PowerMock.expectNew(NewInstanceClass.class).andReturn(mockObject)
```

Actually you could use it even if you are bound to Mockito, [PowerMock contains helpers for Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) to solve exactly this problem that let you use Mockito for all tests and PowerMock to mock constructing objects. Like this:

```
whenNew(Output.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(yourOutputMock);
```

Comment: This is nice, I might have to do this, it'd be a job to add the dependency for PowerMock, but the ability to override the new operator would make this problem trivial.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a setter for "goesHere" and then have setup() check and only change the value of goesHere if its null. This way you could inject a value in testing that would not be overridden. Something like:

```
protected void setGoesHere( Output output ){
    goesHere = output;
} 

@Override
protected void setup(){
    if(goesHere != null) goesHere = new Output();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That would work, but unfortunately I'm doing work on a testing framework, so I don't control MyClass directly, I can't solve the problem by relying on refactoring MyClass.